# Does implementing IEventAggregator in a class other than a ViewModel break MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

When it comes to handlers that are working in the background, is it legal to implement the IEventAggregator on the handler instance which then notifies the ViewModel about the progress? A handler is, in my opinion, not a Model at all.

For example if we got a class `MyHandler` that is starting a thread `MyThread` using function `MyFunction` which is constantly reporting of the progress happening in the handler.

I researched quite a bit if this does break MVVM but found nothing. How's that considered?

Comment: Is the purpose is just to report `progress` in a `progress dialog`?

Comment: @lll No, I want the ViewModel to update some information and bindings.

Comment: You probably didn't find much on the event aggregator doing that sort of work because RX is a favoured alternative.  Same difference, but you're likely to find searching those solutions more rewarding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVVM is not a rigid specification, and while there may be consensus on the broader aspects of the pattern, few would see eye-to-eye on implementation specifics.

Perhaps the question to ask in your case is:  can the view model be independently raised in NUnit or SpecFlow and tested with good coverage.  If the answer is 'yes', then you can take some comfort in having provisioned a big objective of the pattern.  Secondarily you can ask if the handler is strictly a publisher which acts without requiring special knowledge of who the subscribers are.  If the answer is 'yes', that's another favourable indication.  And finally, notwithstanding the need to update and set some bindings, can the view model interact with a mocked handler?  That would be another favourable indication.

Some developers  in your situation might opt to use an IObservable from Reactive Extensions as the publishing vehicle (I count myself in that group), but at that level it's fundamentally an implementation decision and not necessarily a design decision.

Modularity, testability, and transparency all play as big a role in making a robust application as the MVVM pattern does.  If you are achieving those things then whether or not it conforms to someone's concept of MVVM will be based solely upon your communication/persuasive skills.

Comment: The handler will indeed be a strict publisher with no knowledge of the subscribers but I've never seen someone implementing the `IEventAggregator` on models or other classes. That's why I asked and I'm slightly surprised that no one did asked that before. What do you mean by  _might opt to use an IObservable from Reactive Extensions_? Could you go into more detail here?

Comment: Reactive extensions is more "native" (i.e., built in to .NET) than Prism.  It's also more flexible than the aggregator, so developers might opt to use it instead.

Comment: I've looked into the `IObservable` and event mechanism in RX but I'm actually not yet convinced to use RX instead of Caliburn.Micro (or both). I don't see a real difference in having the `IObservable` instead since the IEventAggregator will completely fill my needs. Thank your for your support so far. Finally, would you say that there _is_ a difference between these two structures here when it comes to the situation I mentioned above except that the `IObservable` might be more flexible at some point?

Comment: @Mostey, there is no difference between the two for the situation you described.  I have used them both interchangeably, but have ultimately moved to Rx for models and services.